# MyBatis collection to Array type

Tags: java, arrays, mapping, mybatis

The following code of a MyBatis XML mapper should aggregate column 'value' into a respective array.

```
<resultMap id="cubeTextsHana" type="com.myDao">
    <id property="attribute" column="attribute" javaType="String" />
    <collection property="valueList" ofType="java.lang.String" javaType="String[]">
        <result column="value" />
    </collection>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, since MyBatis states `Class/TypeAlias 'String[]' not found.`. When I change `javaType="list"` and the corresponding type in the DAO as well, it works fine.

Is there a way to use `<collection>` with simple Array type (e.g. String) instead of a Collection type?

Answer (score 1):

resultMap collection processing occurs in class *org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler*

Java Array is not a Collection (*instantiateCollectionPropertyIfAppropriate(ResultMapping, MetaObject)*)
 and then has not method add (*linkObjects(MetaObject, ResultMapping, Object)*)

With Collection types, a new instance of the collection is set in the target property and then all results added into it. Property points to the Collection which sometimes (in case of an ArrayList) extends its internal array, actually copies to a bigger array. Whereas java array is set and pointed directly, every new element is the array would require redefining array and reset property.

So I think result map collection backed by java array is not implemented, would require implementing part of collection management mechanism (what would be the point?)

I guess you may map results to a list and if required call *Collection#toArray()* on the property.